# xsim collections: how to filter on multiple tags?

Tags: xsim

My goal is to have mandatory exercises sorted by subject and then optional exercises sorted by subjection using this MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xsim}

\DeclareExerciseTagging{subject}
\DeclareExerciseTagging{submission}
\xsimsetup{collect}

\DeclareExerciseCollection[subject=philosophy, submission=mandatory]{philosophy-mandatory}
\DeclareExerciseCollection[subject=philosophy, submission=optional]{philosophy-optional}

\begin{filecontents}{exercises.tex}
    \begin{exercise}[solution=true, subject=philosophy, submission=mandatory]
        phil 1, mandatory
        \IfInsideSolutionT{phil 1 solution}
    \end{exercise}
    \begin{exercise}[subject=biology, submission=mandatory]
        bio 1, mandatory
    \end{exercise}
    \begin{exercise}[subject=philosophy, submission=optional]
        phil 2, optional
    \end{exercise}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\input{exercises.tex}

\section{Mandatory}
\subsection{philosophy}
\printcollection{philosophy-mandatory}

\section{Optional}
\subsection{philosophy}
\printcollection{philosophy-optional}

\end{document}
```

However, I really do not understand, why all exercises are under mandatory, and the two philosophy exercises are under optional. I would expect

```
1 Mandatory
1.1 philosopy
    phil 1, mandatory
2 Optional
2.1 philosopy
    phil 2, optional
```

Comment: This is the same as https://github.com/cgnieder/xsim/issues/94 and is resolved with the next update (some time this weekend)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example file works as expected in `xsim` v0.21 (2022/02/13) and gives:

[image]

There are new options `match-all` (new behaviour) and the inverse `match-any` (old behaviour) which control how multiple tags filter the exercises.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to my new package `dbshow` (v1.5) that is powerful to sort, filter and display data. Cause there is no `group-by` option now, items are multi-level sorted by the submission and subject， and then displayed in the one-level list. `group-by` option may come at the next version. Refer to the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/dbshow/dbshow.pdf) of `dbshow` for more options and examples.

[image]

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dbshow}

\dbNewDatabase{ques-db}{
  ques       = tl,
  ans        = tl,
  subject    = str,
  submission = str,
}
\dbNewStyle{ques-style}{ques-db}{
  sort       = {submission, subject},
  item-code  = \par\dbarabic.~\dbuse{ques},
  after-code = \medskip,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{dbitem}{ques-db}
  \dbsave{ques}{phil 1, mandatory}
  \dbsave{subject}{philosophy}
  \dbsave{submission}{mandatory}
\end{dbitem}

\begin{dbitem}{ques-db}
  \dbsave{ques}{bio 1, mandatory}
  \dbsave{subject}{biology}
  \dbsave{submission}{mandatory}
\end{dbitem}

\begin{dbitem}{ques-db}
  \dbsave{ques}{phil 2, optional}
  \dbsave{subject}{philosophy}
  \dbsave{submission}{optional}
\end{dbitem}

\begin{dbitem}{ques-db}
  \dbsave{ques}{bio 2, optional}
  \dbsave{subject}{biology}
  \dbsave{submission}{optional}
\end{dbitem}

\dbshow{ques-style}{ques-db}

\end{document}
```